# Can't read values Inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

Im writing a simple program to illustrate classes and inheritance in java. The program is Bank that has 2 classes Account and Operation where Operation extends Account. Now in main I declared the values in Account and then I started calling the operations from Operation class. now whenever Operation calls the values in Account it return 0 for int and null for string though I added value to it.

Here is the Account:

```
public class Account {

 private String Name;
 private int ID;
 private double Money;

Account()
{

}
Account (String n, int i, double m)
{
    Name = n;
    ID = i;
    Money = m;
}

public void setMoney(double m)
{
    Money = m;
}

public double getMoney()
{    
    return Money;
}

public int getID()
{
    return ID;
}

public String getName()
{
    return Name;
}

public void Check()
{
    System.out.println("Your Name is: " + Name + " Your ID is: " + String.valueOf(ID) + " Your Balance is: " + String.valueOf(Money));
}

}
```

Here is the Operation class:

```
import java.util.Date;


public class Operation extends Account{

private Date TransactionDate;


public void Withdraw(double amount)
{
    double Money = getMoney();
    if (amount > Money)
        System.out.println("The amount is insufficient");
    else
    {
        Money = Money - amount;
        TransactionDate = new Date();
        setMoney(Money);
        System.out.println("The available money is " + String.valueOf(Money) + " at " + String.valueOf(TransactionDate));

    }
}

public void Deposit(double amount)
{
    double Money = getMoney();
    if (amount < 0)
        System.out.println("You cant add minus");
    else
    {
        Money = Money + amount;
        TransactionDate = new Date();
        setMoney(Money);
        System.out.println("Your credits are: " + String.valueOf(Money) + " at " + String.valueOf(TransactionDate));
    }
}

public void Check()
{
    String Name = getName();
    int ID = getID();
    double Money = getMoney();

    System.out.println("Your Name is: " + Name + " Your ID is: " + String.valueOf(ID) + " Your Balance is: " + String.valueOf(Money));
}
}
```

Here is the main:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws NumberFormatException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter your ID");
    int ID = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter your Name");
    String Name = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your Money");
    double Money = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());


    Account a = new Account(Name, ID, Money);
    a.Check();

    Operation o = new Operation();


    while (true) {
        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------");
        System.out
                .println("Enter 1 to withdraw, 2 to Deposit, 3 to Check, 4 to exit ");
        int operation = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        switch (operation) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("enter the amount");
            double withdrawMoney = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            o.Withdraw(withdrawMoney);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("enter the amount");
            double Depositmoney = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            o.Deposit(Depositmoney);
            break;
        case 3:
            o.Check();
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("enter between 1 and 4 only");
        }

        if (operation == 4)
            break;
    }

}

}
```

I really don't know why Operation cant read the values I added to Account since Operation extends Account can you please explain it to me the reason and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have created two different objects Account with constructor and Operation which are not related to each other

You are initializing Account object & trying to your operations on object of Operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate objects -- one an `Account`, and one an `Operation`.

An instance of your Operation class has a name, ID and money - but they're not the same name, ID and money as other instances of Account or Operation.

One way to fix it would be to add a constructor to Operation:

```
class Operation {
    Operation(String n, int i, double m) {
        super( n, i, m );
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: After this Rather than 
Account a = new Account(Name, ID, Money);
    a.Check();

    Operation o = new Operation();

Use

 Operation o = new Operation(Name, ID, Money);